# How to get usage stats of a REST API?

Tags: web-services, symfony, analytics

I have a big Symfony3 project, with a REST API and many webservices.

I'm looking for a bundle, tool, and/or best practices to get usage analytics on my webservices.

Comment: You can use the Apache/Nginx/lighthttp access log.

Answer (score 0):

Most cases, you don't need special bundles for that. You can analyze your webserver's log. It will be even much easier if you have more than 1 server under load-balancer.

For analytics you can use ElasticSearch + Logstash + Kibana (ELK). There are a lot of tutorials how to set up it on the internet ([1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04), [2](https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/), [3](https://thepracticalsysadmin.com/introduction-to-logstashelasticsearchkibana/))